# How to use for loop exactly in script plainess elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I using elasticsearch version 8.10 . I'm writing a script to check input field 'seniority' have enough condition to search result.

Here is demo my index:

```
PUT target_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "targetoperator": { "type": "keyword" },
      "targetvalue": { 
        "type": "float"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After, I create a document above:

```
PUT target_index/_doc/1
{
  "targetoperator": [">"],
  "targetvalue": [4]
}
```

I run script above:

```
GET target_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "script": {
      "script": { 
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": """
          double userCriteria = params.userTarget.seniority;
          if (doc['targetoperator'].length > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < doc['targetoperator'].length; ++i) {
              if (doc['targetoperator'][i] == "<=") {
                if (!(userCriteria <= doc['targetvalue'][i])) {
                  return false;
                }
              } else if (doc['targetoperator'][i] == ">") {
                if (!(userCriteria > doc['targetvalue'][i])) {
                  return false;
                }
              } else if (doc['targetoperator'][i] == "==") {
                if (!(userCriteria == doc['targetvalue'][i])) {
                  return false;
                }
              }
            }
          }
          return true;
        """, 
        "params": {
          "userTarget": {
            "gender": "male",
            "seniority": 5
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "_source": [
    "targetoperator",
    "targetvalue"
  ]
}
```

After run query, I found result return about document = 1.
But I update document = 1 again:

```
PUT target_index/_doc/1
{
  "targetoperator": [">", "<="],
  "targetvalue": [4, 8]
}
```

I run again script query. No matching results were found.

If this correct, it will return document = 1 because seniority = 5 > 4 and 5 <= 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues here.

Since you need AND logic between all your conditions, you need to change your script to not return true/false immediately, but instead store that into a variable (e.g. `result`), like this:

```
GET target_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "script": {
      "script": { 
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": """
          double userCriteria = params.userTarget.seniority;
          boolean result = true;
          if (doc['targetoperator'].length > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < doc['targetoperator'].length; ++i) {
              if (doc['targetoperator'][i] == "<=") {
                if (!(userCriteria <= doc['targetvalue'][i])) {
                  result = result && false;
                }
              } else if (doc['targetoperator'][i] == ">") {
                if (!(userCriteria > doc['targetvalue'][i])) {
                  result = result && false;
                }
              } else if (doc['targetoperator'][i] == "==") {
                if (!(userCriteria == doc['targetvalue'][i])) {
                  result = result && false;
                }
              }
            }
          }
          return result;
        """, 
        "params": {
          "userTarget": {
            "gender": "male",
            "seniority": 5
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "_source": [
    "targetoperator",
    "targetvalue"
  ]
}
```

However, we are not done yet, since your target* doc values arrays are not stored the way you have specified, but in lexicographical order.

Running the following query shows that:

```
GET target_index/_search
{
  "docvalue_fields": ["targetoperator", "targetvalue"]
}
```

Returns

```
    "fields": {
      "targetvalue": [
        4,
        8
      ],
      "targetoperator": [
        "<=",
        ">"
      ]
    }
```

As you can see the operators are not in the same order, i.e. `<=` comes before `>`. Hence, even with the modified logic it's not going to work.

You need to store your conditions differently, using an `object` array would suffer from the same issue as objects fields are flattened. Using `nested` helps, but the script would be evaluated in the context of each single nested condition and you would need some post-processing logic to make sure that all your conditions match, i.e. in this case, you'd need to verify in your application code that the nested matching doc_count is 2.

Aside from the fact that using scripting is discouraged because of performance issues, I'd strongly suggest you revise the way you want to apply your conditions. I can suggest using [search templates](https://opster.com/guides/elasticsearch/how-tos/how-to-provide-a-simple-query-interface-using-search-templates/), which can help you build very powerful queries.

Comment: I thank you for your wonderful explanations

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad it helped!

Comment: I tried edit index with my field have type `nested`. 
PUT target_index/_doc/1
{
  "targetoperator": [
    {
      "valStr": "<"
    },
    {
      "valStr": "<="
    }
  ],
  "targetvalue": [
    {
      "valDou": 6
    },
    {
      "valDou": 5.5
    }
  ]
}

I tried check `doc['targetoperator.valStr'].length > 0` . Unforternately, it have length = 0, I still do not understand what reason length = 0. I'm sure that document = 1 have values

Comment: If you use nested, you need to collocate the operator and value within the same object. But really, your time would be better invested into building dynamic queries using search templates